# Баг или фича, нельзя повторно перейти по NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swift, apple, swiftui

Вопрос, вот перешел я на страницу в NavigationLink, все как-бы и работает, только если я возвращаюсь назад, вернулся на главный экран успешно, но вот при повторном нажатии на любую ссылку в NavigationLink не могу никуда "провалиться". Что я делаю не так?

Всем заранее спасибо=)

Вот исходник мой:
VStack думаю будет достаточно

```html
VStack
                        {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Services")) {
                                Text("Services")
                                    .padding().accentColor(Color.orange)
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Top Prices")) {
                                Text("Top prices")
                                    .padding().accentColor(Color.orange)
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Call now and create new order")) {
                                Text("Call now and create new order")
                                    .padding().foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Contact us...")) {
                                Text("Contact us...")
                                    .padding().foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("About us...")) {
                                Text("About us...")
                                    .padding().foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                            }
                    }
```

[[image: Слева часть главного окна, справа окно уже второе.[1]]

Comment: Вы бы лучше все же полный текст примера в виде текста приложили, чтобы можно было воспроизвести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это баг симулятора (нужно тапнуть по другой ссылке и она откроется, после этого будет открываться та, которая не открывалась, и наоборот), на устройстве всё работает правильно.